# finding sth with loops by indexing in R

Tags: r, indexing

Create a for loop that checks whether a numeric vector has at least two zeros in
a row. If so, it prints the position (index) of the first zero.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include a reproducible question as suggested here [reprex] include your data (as a dataframe object or use `dput("yourdata")`, the code you have tried and your expected output. This will make it more likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version by using `rle` + `inverse.rle`

```
findConZeros <- function(x) {
  u <- rle(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),""))==0)
  u$values <- with(u,lengths>=2&values)
  which(inverse.rle(u))
}
```

such that

```
> findConZeros(1200011)
[1] 3 4 5

> findConZeros(40400)
[1] 4 5
```

---

Below is a `for` loop version

```
findConZeros_forloop <- function(x) {
  s <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),""))
  res <- c()
  for (i in seq_along(s)) {
    if (all(s[i:(i+1)]=="0") & i < length(s)) res <- c(res,i,i+1)
  }
  unique(res)
}
```

which gives

```
> findConZeros_forloop(1200011)
[1] 3 4 5

> findConZeros_forloop(40400)
[1] 4 5
```